# How can I add a class to a button when a Formik Form isSubmitting?

Tags: reactjs, formik

How can I add a class to a button when a Formik Form isSubmitting?

I can see rendering different text if the form isSubmitting eg                     `{isSubmitting ? "Please wait..." : "LOG IN"}`
 - but how can I add a class/ className to the button?

```
<button
    type="submit"
    className={`btn`}
    onClick={() => {
    api.submitForm();
    }}
    disabled={api.isSubmitting}
>
    LOG IN
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
className={'btn ' + (isSubmitting ? 'btn-while-submitting' : '')}
```

Or using something like [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

```
className={classNames('btn', {
    ['btn-while-submitting']: isSubmitting,
})}
```